# What does enable-static-engine do in Openssl ./config

Tags: tls, openssl

I am using a command to compile OpenSSL from source. I need to remove un-needed parameters that enable settings I do not need. One of the settings:

```
enable-static-engine
```

What does this parameter do?

How can I get the help of ./config? I tried `./config -help` but that does not display the ./config parameters.

Comment: I googled the option and got: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the README, which is the first thing you should read when compiling the software by your own:

```
 INSTALLATION
 ------------

 See the appropriate file:
        INSTALL         Linux, Unix, Windows, OpenVMS, ...
```

And, from the INSTALL file one should read according to the README:

```
  no-static-engine
                   Don't build the statically linked engines. This only
                   has an impact when not built "shared".
```

To understand what this means I recommend to read the section *How do I build a "dynamic" ENGINE?* in the README.ENGINE file. It is not trivial to understand, it is probably irrelevant for most users of OpenSSL and it is not about security but about programming, i.e. off-topic here.